# New version of SwipeRefreshLayout causes wrong draw of views

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I've got a ViewPager (backed by a AbstractBrowsePagerAdapter) composed of Fragments. Each fragment inflates a layout with a SwipeRefreshLayout as the root. I've recently updated to the support-v4:21.0.0 library. The new SwipeRefreshLayout uses a circle progress bar instead of the linear vertical progress bar as shown on the screenshot below.

When I pull to refresh, swipe right, create a new fragment in the ViewPager at the same index as the one where I pulled to refresh and then go to that new Fragment, the previous view still appears on top of my new content.

[image: Bug with new SwipeRefreshLayout]

As you can see on the screenshot, the "empty directory" textview and the "circle progressbar" are still appearing from the previous fragment that was destroyed.

1. This only occurs when the SwipeRefreshLayout is in the loading state (the loader is displayed on the screen)
2. This doesn't occur with the previous version of the SwipeRefreshLayout
3. The hierarchyviewer tool doesn't work when the bug occurs. It works before, it works if i restart the application but doesn't work when in the bugging state.
4. When I'm dumping the view with DDMS, the views from the previous fragment don't appear.

This seems like a bug in the new SwipeRefreshLayout but I couldn't find anybody having the same issue and it doesn't seem to be reported on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=SwipeRefreshLayout&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles

I'm looking for a workaround, forcing the views from the former fragment to be removed for good.

Comment: swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

Comment: Nope. The correct answer is below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by calling clearAnimation() on the onPause() method of my Fragment

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    swipeLayout.clearAnimation();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: It works great when you are replacing fragments. However in the case of the ViewPager, the onPause() method on the fragment is not called.

Comment: I have a similar problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821940/replacing-fragments-quickly-causes-a-weird-screenshot-of-the-previous-fragment-t . Removing all children views of the fragment's view in the onDestroyView of the fragment also seems to "fix" it though I don't know why